# Xcode 7 - Multiple Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard

After finishing an app, what code do I have to put in appdelegate.m to be able to make it run view controllers depending on the device's size?

Comment: It is not advisable to make different storyboard for each device size. Try to use autolayout or autoresizing concept.

Comment: It is not advisable to use different  storyboards but if you must you can place this code in the app delegate to determine the iOS devices screen size: " let iOSDeviceScreenSize : CGSize = UIScreen().bounds.size ", then you can just follow this: http://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/organizing-xcode-projects-using-multiple-storyboards/

Comment: Emptyless, do I have to put it in the - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

Comment: also that is SWIFT, I need OBJECTIVE-C.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use multiple storyboards to handle different devices in an iOS app.  Please see the Apple documentation:

[Adaptive User Interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/)

And in particular the section on Auto Layout to learn how to properly handle making your user interface adaptable to current and future devices.